# How to inject Audio into specific slides on a PowerPoint demo?

Tags: audio, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

My son is doing a presentation to his class and is working on a PowerPoint file.  He asked me something that has me stumped.

He wants 4 things.

1. He has an audio file that he wants to start playing automatically when he reaches the 3rd slide.
2. The audio should stop playing when he exits the 6th slide.
3. If the audio file ends while he is still on slides 3 to 6, the audio should start over.
4. When he exits slide 6, the audio should not abruptly end, but fade out.

Can PowerPoint do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert the sound on the third slide. PowerPoint will ask if you want it to start playing automatically.  Say yes.

Then in the custom animation settings, you can tell PPT to play the song for nn seconds or for however many slides you like.

Exactly how you do this depends on which version you have.  If you can't work it out for your version, let us know which it is.

PPT won't restart audio w/o returning to the slide where the audio began, but you might snookier it into doing what you want by putting the same sound file on the subsequent slides and setting them NOT to start automatically but on click; he'd have to click them to start the sound over.

I don't know of any way to get the sound to fade though.